# Importing a list of modules in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

My vision is somewhere in the lines of:

```
const usedModules = [MatIconModule, MatInputModule, ...];

for(let i=0; i<usedModules.length; i++) {
    import { usedModules[i] } from '@angular/material';
}
@NgModule({
    imports: usedModules,
    exports: usedModules,
})
export class AppMaterilaModule {}
```

Obviously this does not work. Has anybody any ideas how to create a dynamic import statement, i.e listing the usedModules only once?

Comment: How many modules do you have(!) that would make this a consideration? If the modules are so similar then it is more likely that a redesign for them should be considered.

Comment: You can't. Modules are imported in a static way so that the bundler (WebPack, typically) is able to know what is actually used in your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically load modules with [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs). It'll look like:

```js
const plugins = [
  './plugin1.js',
  './plugin2.js'
];

const loadPlugins = (plugins) => {
  return plugins.map( (path) => window.SystemJS.import(path) );
};

Promise.all(loadPlugins(plugins)).then(() => {
    // Everything is ready now
});
```

I hope I understand the question right.

Answer (score 0):

Modules are used for bootstrapping the application, so at that point cannot be decided what is used. The only possibility you have (which goes in this direction) is making small modules with only necessary dependencies and then using Lazy Loading, so only loading the dependencies if a certain route called. But that will lead to more time spent on page loading instead of application load. And it does not work with AOT compiling.